# Intellij - new group in live templates

Tags: intellij-idea

I have idea of creating groups of Java templates for android development. If I open Settings > Live templates I have provided groups of templates, one named "user". Is it possible to add a new group for my collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - If you clock the add button [image: add icon] in the live templates settings dialog, one of the options is "Template Group". Select it and follow the prompts.

Alternatively, select a template, open the context menu (i.e. right click) and select "Move". At the bottom of the side menu that opens will be "New Group".